# Исключение при работе с базой данных

Tags: c#, access

Суть такова, первый раз работаю с C# и файликом базы данных Microsoft Access.
Ошибок нет, но вызывает исключения класса. Пожалуйста, пересмотрите код, он не велик. И ткните, где не так.

```
class DB
{
    static string connectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "datasource=Kursach.mdb";
    static OleDbConnection myOleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    static OleDbCommand myOleDbCommand = myOleDbConnection.CreateCommand();
    static OleDbDataReader myOleDbDataReader = myOleDbCommand.ExecuteReader();

    public string sql_query(string query, string row)
    {
        myOleDbCommand.CommandText = query;
        myOleDbConnection.Open();
        myOleDbDataReader.Read();
        return myOleDbDataReader[""] + row;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Разобрался, действительно проблема была в подключении.. Спасибо кто отозвался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Загляните [сюда](http://connectionstrings.com/access-2007). 
Может ошибка в строке коннекта. Например не datasource а Data Source